# Bottom item on the DrawerLayout

Tags: android, drawerlayout

I'm trying to do the same thing @lnamdar asked in this question ([Drawer layout with fixed menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331761/drawer-layout-with-fixed-menu-item)). I'm trying to get a better explanation on their solution.

I'm trying this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"   
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<!-- The main content view -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:text="This is the footer text"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<!-- The navigation drawer -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:background="@android:color/black"/>
```

But this is causing the list view not to show and when I toggle open/close the only thing that I see is the footer.
I tried to put both the listView and the footer textView inside the RelativeLayout but then it crashes with a ClassCastException on the Layout Params used on the Drawer Layout class.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their attempt with the RelativeLayout was giving unexpected result since it wasnt inside the content frame. Explanation is pretty straightforward, since the RelativeLayout is parent of the `ListView` that hold menu items we move the gravity to it, instead using `ListView` with same gravity.
 Here is what I did:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
```

```
    <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/logout_item"
        android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp"
        android:text="@string/logout"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Don't forget to run HierarchyViewer to get rid of unnecessary ViewGroup.

Comment: Thanks Nikola, meanwhile I had gotten to the same conclusion and was able to do it. Really appreciate the help!